# connection.requestAirdrop fail: StructError

Tags: web3.js, airdrop

I am running a hello world demo of Solana. However, I'm facing a problem. This is my code:

```
import {
    Keypair,
    Connection,
    PublicKey,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    TransactionInstruction,
    Transaction,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  } from '@solana/web3.js';
  import fs from 'mz/fs';
  import path from 'path';
  
  const PROGRAM_KEYPAIR_PATH = path.join(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/program'),
    'program-keypair.json'
  );
  
  async function main() {
    
    console.log("Launching client...");
  
    let connection = new Connection('https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=?????????', 'confirmed');
  
    const secretKeyString = await fs.readFile(PROGRAM_KEYPAIR_PATH, {encoding: 'utf8'});
    const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString));
    const programKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
    let programId: PublicKey = programKeypair.publicKey;

    const triggerKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    const airdropRequest = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      triggerKeypair.publicKey,
      LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropRequest);
  
    console.log('--Pinging Program ', programId.toBase58());
    const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
      keys: [{pubkey: triggerKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true}],
      programId,
      data: Buffer.alloc(0),
    });
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      new Transaction().add(instruction),
      [triggerKeypair],
    );
  }
  
  main().then(
    () => process.exit(),
    err => {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(-1);
    },
  );
```

There is a problem with `requestAirdrop()`, this is the error output:

```
StructError: Expected the value to satisfy a union of `type | type`, but received: [object Object]
    at validate (/opt/solana/youtube-tutorial/hello-solana/node_modules/superstruct/src/struct.ts:184:19)
    at Object.create (/opt/solana/youtube-tutorial/hello-solana/node_modules/superstruct/src/struct.ts:135:18)
    at Connection.requestAirdrop (/opt/solana/youtube-tutorial/hello-solana/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5551:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async main (/opt/solana/youtube-tutorial/hello-solana/src/client/main.ts:44:28) {
  value: {
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    result: '3zzpynYRpQYEM3iLrLaeYNV4UhaBu97WrcNNvFxkGWicEKpP6Zd5Azp7iEHxM2jkPTHsU1AuqsmwWSHwGLZr3mYy'
  },
  type: 'union',
  refinement: undefined,
  key: undefined,
  path: [],
  branch: [
    {
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      result: '3zzpynYRpQYEM3iLrLaeYNV4UhaBu97WrcNNvFxkGWicEKpP6Zd5Azp7iEHxM2jkPTHsU1AuqsmwWSHwGLZr3mYy'
    }
  ],
  failures: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

You can find the whole code [here](https://github.com/Coding-and-Crypto/Rust-Solana-Tutorial/blob/master/hello-solana/src/client/main.ts).

My specifications:

```
Windows11, wsl2: ubuntu 20.04，
ts-node: v10.9.1
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello-solana",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "ts-node src/client/main.ts",
      "clean": "npm run clean:program",
      "build:program": "cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/program",
      "clean:program": "cargo clean --manifest-path=./src/program/Cargo.toml && rm -rf ./dist",
      "test:program": "cargo test-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program/Cargo.toml"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "@solana/web3.js": "=1.89.1",
      "mz": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.1",
      "@types/mz": "^2.7.2",
      "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
      "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "engines": {
      "node": ">=14.0.0"
  }
}
```

The RPC I use: `https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=???????` and `https://quiet-young-pallet.solana-devnet.quiknode.pro/????`

I didn't encounter this error when using "requestAirdrop" in other projects (unrelated but I have reached the request limit). Here, I want to know why I encountered a `StructError`

Comment: Strange. Can you look for the line inside `requestAirdrop` that reads `const res = create(unsafeRes, RequestAirdropRpcResult)` in the files of `/opt/solana/youtube-tutorial/hello-solana/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib`, `console.log(unsafeRes)` and let us know what it contains?

Comment: Can you create an interactive playground that reproduces the error, like this one? https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mrki1s?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

The @solana/web3.js version is too old

Try updating the package to fix it

Comment: I have tried the newest version, but the result is the same.

Comment: Which version did you use? Can you post all of your code and configuration including RPC endpoint.

Comment: I have modified the post, u can get all of my code and configuartion. For RPC endpoint, I hide some content, but you can see which provider I use.